# Extract specific string from input

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @input2 VARCHAR(100) = '(USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25%';
DECLARE @output2 VARCHAR(100);

SET @output2 = SUBSTRING(@input2, CHARINDEX('(', @input2), CHARINDEX(')', @input2) - CHARINDEX('(', @input2) + 1);

SELECT @output2 AS ParsedOutput;
```

input1:

```
(USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25%
```

required output: `(1 Month)`

input2:

```
SOFR (1 Month) 3%
```

required output: `(1 Month)`

input3:

```
Daily SOFR 1.5%
```

required output: `Daily`.

Thanks for your help.

Tried above query and working for input2, not working for input1 and input3. My requirement is for it to work with all inputs.

Comment: And the version of SSMS is not relevant, SSMS is purely a client UI, we need the version of your SQL Server engine (`select @@version`).

Comment: input1: (USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25%, required output: (1 Month), output: (1 USD), this is wrong output.
input2: SOFR (1 Month) 3%, required output: (1 Month), --output: (1 Month)
input3: Daily SOFR 1.5%, required output: Daily. -- output: ()

Comment: SSMS version 2016

Comment: SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is a client program that connects to SQL Servers to query and manage them. What version of SSMS you're using has no bearing on this question.

Comment: And [edit] any clarifications directly into your question - don't add in comments

Comment: The "parsing" query is using brackets to find and extract information, how do you expect it to find and extract `Daily` from the input `Daily SOFR 1.5%` that contains no brackets?

Comment: Telling us you use any version of SSMS is like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio. Fine for some; alarming from a mechanic.

Comment: Is it a test question?

Comment: project requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use a case expression to compute it differently when no brackets exist. And do a reverse search, i.e. find your brackets from the right rather than the left. I expect you'll have more missing use-cases in your real data, but this should give you what you need to solve them i.e. more branches in case expression.

```
select
  TestValue [Input]
  , case when y.LastOpeningBracket > 0
    then reverse(substring(reverse(TestValue), y.LastClosingBracket, y.LastOpeningBracket - y.LastClosingBracket + 1))
    else substring(TestValue, 0, charindex(' ', TestValue))
    end [Output]
from (
  values
  ('(USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25%'),
  ('SOFR (1 Month) 3%'),
  ('Daily SOFR 1.5%')
) x (TestValue)
cross apply (
  values
  (charindex('(', reverse(x.TestValue)), charindex(')', reverse(x.TestValue)))
) y (LastOpeningBracket, LastClosingBracket);
```

Returns:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| (USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25% | (1 Month) |
| SOFR (1 Month) 3% | (1 Month) |
| Daily SOFR 1.5% | Daily |

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for words around "SOFR" I suggest you use `PATINDEX` to find your patterns, as this should give more robust (less false positives) pattern matching in case of strings with more brackets.

See comments in code for explanation of the logic

```
SELECT Input,
    CASE
        -- Check what pattern was matched and extract value
        -- Note: PATINDEX returns 0 when no match found
        WHEN DailyPattern > 0 THEN SUBSTRING( Input, DailyPattern, LEN( 'Daily' ))
        WHEN MonthlyPattern > 0 THEN SUBSTRING( Input, MonthlyPattern + LEN( 'SOFR' ) + 1, CHARINDEX(')', Input, MonthlyPattern ) - MonthlyPattern - LEN( 'SOFR' ))
        ELSE ''
    END AS [Period]
FROM(
    -- Find starting index for each type of pattern
    SELECT Input, PATINDEX( '%Daily SOFR%', Input ) AS DailyPattern, PATINDEX( '%SOFR (_ Month)%', Input ) AS MonthlyPattern
    FROM ( VALUES
            ( '(USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25%' ),
            ( 'SOFR (1 Month) 3%' ),
            ( 'Daily SOFR 1.5%' ),
            ( 'Test' ),
            ( '(USD) Test for more brackets SOFR (1 Month) (5.25%)' )
        ) AS Inputs( Input )
    ) AS Patterns
```

Note: code like `LEN( 'Daily' )` was left for logic illustration purposes. You can replace this with "magic numbers" i.e. 4

Output:

```
Input                                               Period
--------------------------------------------------- ----------
(USD) Term Loan SOFR (1 Month) 5.25%                (1 Month)
SOFR (1 Month) 3%                                   (1 Month)
Daily SOFR 1.5%                                     Daily
Test                                                
(USD) Test for more brackets SOFR (1 Month) (5.25%) (1 Month)
```